# Display Double withouth scientific notation

Tags: java, json, jackson

What to do If I have a big double and I want to output it into json document as a number like so 222222222.25 ?

I found many solutions but they all handle this as a string:

```
 System.out.println("DOUBLE1: " + String.format("%.2f", 222222222.2502));
 System.out.println("DOUBLE2: " + String.valueOf(new Double(String.format("%.2f", 222222222.2502))));
```

Output :
    DOUBLE1: 222222222.25
    DOUBLE2: 2.2222222225E8

So what I want is to have the number 222222222.25 in json. How to do that?

I need to get the following using jackson:
    {value: 222222222.25}
and not:
     {value: "222222222.25"}

Comment: Can you share your Jackson code with us?  AFAIK if your POJO uses a `Double` or `BigDecimal` then Jackson should use the correct serialization as a number automatically.

Comment: The problem is the json value property can be either an integer, a double, or a string. So I am mapping to an Object and deciding what the value is. The document model is also very big to post here. The mapping is no problem but I want to have the non scientific notation in the json.

Comment: Just the same type consistently throughout.  If you need to work the field as a number, then use a numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert string to double before writing it to JSON file.

Use Double.parseDouble to get it work.

Comment: Hmm, doesn seem to work, or I am doing something wrong ...

Comment: Let me clarify whether I get your point clearly, do you want put the double value into the JSON file without the "E8" suffix?

Comment: Yes, as a number, and not a string, {"name": "someName", "value": 2222222.22, "something": "something", ... }